# the gristle in my knee after torn PCL

Tags: injury, recovery, injury-prevention

I have an unsettling gristly noise in my right knee when I squat (only when I squat thank God!) that's related to my torn PCL. I am just now getting my stabilizing muscles reactivated and thus full use back of my leg. I believe a meniscus tear would have shown up on the MRI that diagnosed the PCL tear, so now I'm just wondering if this means

- I should avoid squatting using my right knee / stabilize and plant on left leg
- if this will 'go away' as I continue to strengthen and fully activate the stability muscles
- if this means I will need another knee in the future (when? coming up on thirties right now)

for example, I screwed up something in my left knee in a prior motorcycle fall and sometimes have a 'small click'; which previously was a 'bigger click' that seems to have 'smoothed out', and I'm wondering if the cartilage in my right knee just needs some time to sort out too.

Comment: I have no injuries that I'm aware of, but have what I think is that same "gristly" noise in my knees when I squat (even bodyweight) sometimes.